# ¿porqué no puedo pasar datos de un Jtable a mi JasperReports?

Tags: java, netbeans, jasper-reports, jaspersoft

tengo el siguiente código que genera un reporte de facturación:

```
    private void imprimir_facturaActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                 
         List<reporte_productos> listaProducto = new ArrayList<reporte_productos>();
               
         int filas= tabla_factura.getRowCount();
                
                for (int i = 0; i < filas; i++)
                {
                    reporte_productos p = new  reporte_productos(tabla_factura.getValueAt(i, 0).toString(),tabla_factura.getValueAt(i, 1).toString(),tabla_factura.getValueAt(i, 2).toString(),tabla_factura.getValueAt(i, 3).toString(),tabla_factura.getValueAt(i, 4).toString());
                    listaProducto.add(p);
                }
                
        try {
             
                
                
                 JasperReport reporte = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(getClass().getResource("factura.jasper"));
                 
                Map<String, String> parametros = new HashMap<String, String>();
                parametros.put("nunfac", num_factura.getText());
                parametros.put("cliente", nom_cliente.getText());
                parametros.put("cedulacli",ced_cliente.getText());
                parametros.put("vendedor",(String) combousuarios.getSelectedItem());
                parametros.put("fechafac",fecha_fact.getText());
                parametros.put("subtotal",st_compra.getText());
                parametros.put("totalp",total_p.getText());
                
              
                
               
                JasperPrint imprimir= JasperFillManager.fillReport(reporte, parametros, new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(listaProducto));
                
                JasperViewer.viewReport(imprimir);
             
                
        } catch (JRException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Principal_Vendedor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }
```

Mi Jtable contiene la descripcion de todos los productos comprados (codigo,descripcion,precio,cantidad y total)
aqui esta la clase

```
public class reporte_productos {
    private String codigo;
    private String descripcion;
    private String precio;
    private String cantidad;
    private String total;

    public reporte_productos(String codigo, String descripcion, String precio, String cantidad, String total) {
        this.codigo = codigo;
        this.descripcion = descripcion;
        this.precio = precio;
        this.cantidad = cantidad;
        this.total = total;
    }

    public String getCodigo() {
        return codigo;
    }

    public String getDescripcion() {
        return descripcion;
    }

    public String getPrecio() {
        return precio;
    }

    public String getCantidad() {
        return cantidad;
    }

    public String getTotal() {
        return total;
    }

    public void setCodigo(String codigo) {
        this.codigo = codigo;
    }

    public void setDescripcion(String descripcion) {
        this.descripcion = descripcion;
    }

    public void setPrecio(String precio) {
        this.precio = precio;
    }

    public void setCantidad(String cantidad) {
        this.cantidad = cantidad;
    }

    public void setTotal(String total) {
        this.total = total;
    }
    
}
```

trato de pasar esos datos en un Arraylist y utilizo el JRBeanCollectionDataSource(lista), pero me sale un **error** en toda la linea del JasperPrint

> no suitable method found for fillReport(JasperReport,Map<String,String>,JRBeanCollectionDataSource(list)) method JasperFillManager.fillReport(String,Map<String,Object>,Connection) is not applicable
> (argument mismatch; JasperReport cannot be converted to String)
> (argument mismatch; Map<String, String>cannot be converted to  Map<String, Object>)